# Flask-Login/Flask-Session - Links from external site

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-session

While working with Flask, Flask-Login and Flask-Session, I ran into the following problem:

When clicking on a link on an external site (cross-domain), that links to a route that's secured with `@login_required`, flask-logins `_load_user`-function is unable to retrieve the user information (since no cookie was sent with the cross-domain-request). (Without using the decorator, `current_user.is_authenticated` appears to be `False`.)

(from `flask_login.login_manager.py`)

```
if user is None:
        config = current_app.config
        cookie_name = config.get('REMEMBER_COOKIE_NAME', COOKIE_NAME)
        header_name = config.get('AUTH_HEADER_NAME', AUTH_HEADER_NAME)
        has_cookie = (cookie_name in request.cookies and
                      session.get('_remember') != 'clear')
        if has_cookie:
            cookie = request.cookies[cookie_name]
            user = self._load_user_from_remember_cookie(cookie)
        elif self._request_callback:
            user = self._load_user_from_request(request)
        elif header_name in request.headers:
            header = request.headers[header_name]
            user = self._load_user_from_header(header)
```

In case the decorator was used, the request will be redirected to `/?next=/protectedView`. If just using `current_user.is_authenticated`, it will result `False`.

The session cookie gets re-created and overwritten every time I click on refresh. However, if I click in the URL bar and hit enter, the user loader is able to access the remember_cookie and load user data without creating a new session.

Is there any simple and convenient way to allow loading user data when entering a protected route from within another domain?

**Update:** I found out that setting `REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE` to `None` instead of `Strict` will cause flask-login to login the user. The link now redirects to the correct page.